# PrimeFaces. TreeTable multiple row shift selection event not fired

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 4.0. And when i select some rows with shift key, "select" event not fired.But select with ctrl key fired event correctly.

TreeTable code:

```
<p:treeTable id="reportTreeTable" value="#{reportListBean.reportTree.rootNode}" var="report"
                     selectionMode="multiple" selection="#{reportListBean.reportTree.treeSelection}">
            <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{reportListBean.reportTree.onNodeExpand}" update=":actionMenuForm" />
            <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{reportListBean.reportTree.onNodeSelect}" update=":actionMenuForm"/>
            <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{reportListBean.reportTree.onNodeUnselect}" update=":actionMenuForm"/>

            <p:column headerText="Название">
                 <h:outputText value="#{report.data.label}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="URI">
                <h:outputText value="#{report.data.uriString}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Дата">
                <h:outputText value="#{report.data.creationDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PrimeFaces 4.0 treeTable on selectionMode="multiple" with "shift" key not fired event "select" to server.

Comment: The problem still persists in PF 5.0

Comment: Is there any chance of fixing this in future versions?